# Trying to create an Array with sizes from a text file

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a 2D array with sizes specified in a text file and fill it in.

The text file has the following 2 lines:

```
widthOfTheArray=4
heightOfTheArray=4
```

**My Code:**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[][] gameBoard = gameBoardCreator();
        fillBoard(gameBoard);
    }

    public static String[][] gameBoardCreator() throws IOException {
            String valueWidth;
            String valueHeight;
            int Rows;
            int Cols;

            String width = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(1);
            String[] widthSplitter = width.split("=");
            valueWidth = widthSplitter[1];
            Cols = Integer.parseInt(valueWidth);

            String height = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(2);
            String[] heightSplitter = height.split("=");
            valueHeight = heightSplitter[1];
            Rows = Integer.parseInt(valueHeight);
            String[][] board = new String[Cols][Rows];

            return board;
    }
    public static void fillBoard(String[][] board){
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
                board[row][col] = " X ";
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it it throws a lot of exceptions which I really don't know what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an element from the index, `2` which is not available. Note that the first index of a `List` is `0` and the second index is `1`.

Trying to access an element beyond the bounds causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown.

Replace

```
String width = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(1);
```

with

```
String width = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(0);
```

and

```
String height = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(2);
```

with

```
String height = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(1);
```

Given below is the working code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[][] gameBoard = gameBoardCreator();
        fillBoard(gameBoard);
    }

    public static String[][] gameBoardCreator() throws IOException {
        String valueWidth;
        String valueHeight;
        int Rows;
        int Cols;

        String width = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(0);
        String[] widthSplitter = width.split("=");
        valueWidth = widthSplitter[1];
        Cols = Integer.parseInt(valueWidth);

        String height = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("enemy_territory")).get(1);
        String[] heightSplitter = height.split("=");
        valueHeight = heightSplitter[1];
        Rows = Integer.parseInt(valueHeight);
        String[][] board = new String[Cols][Rows];

        return board;
    }

    public static void fillBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
                board[row][col] = " X ";
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X 
 X  X  X  X
```

Content of the file, `enemy_territory`:

```
widthOfTheArray=4
heightOfTheArray=4
```

Comment: Did it but it still doesn't compile.

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 - I've posted the working code with the output. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help it works. The problem was that the text file was in a directory and my path was wrong.